# How to manage enterprise keywords or managed metadata columns in InfoPath and Workspace

Tags: managed-metadata, infopath

I've got errors using more complex SharePoint fields like enterprise keywords, managed metadata or custom fields that contain code with InfoPath and Workspace clients. Is this really not supported? Is there any workaround, e.g. treat as basic string field or whatever?

There must be something...otherwise this would mean, items with metadata tags cannot be managed with InfoPath and cannot be offline with Workspace. ????

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct. InfoPath really doesn't support managed metadata.

The Managed Metadata field is such a good idea (don't start me on the implementation, though) that lots of people want to use it - but it's unusable with InfoPath. Crazy.

Still, at least [Microsoft are aware of the issue](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/eab2a513-ccae-4e8e-a07b-7a07f47179d6/).